# Can't send sitemap for my Multistore to Google

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, sitemaps, multi-website

I have a rare error. I have translated my website in to multiple languages, using Magento, like www.example.com/de
Now, I have added www.example.com/de in Search console and I want to send the sitemap, Google tells me to add the name of the sitemap that the page has to have structure of www.example.com/de/... but I can't do that because I have to create a folder in the root /de and if I go to www.example.com/de I see an error 403. Please suggest how I could do this, Thanks!

Comment: You don't _necessarily_ have to put your sitemap into a sub folder.
You could simply set the file name to be `de-sitemap.xml` for your German store and i.e. `en-sitemap.xml` for your English store and set the path to be `/`. What is your further requirement in this that makes need to have this particular structure?

Answer (score 0):

Google allows you to add multiple sitemaps for each domain. You are not required to have these maps in different sub-folders. You will need to create ones with different names for each language. for example `de-sitemap.xml` or `sitemap-de.xml`

1. In your Magento admin navigate to **Catalog -> Google Sitemap**
2. Create a sitemap with different names for each language. A language is usually associated with a store view. For example:

   ```
   Filename   => sitemap-de.xml
   Path       => /
   Store View => German
   ```
3. Add the sitemap for each language to your Google Search Console. In our example it would be `http://www.yourdomain.com/sitemap-de.xml`

Magento can update your sitemap regularly. Go to **System > Configuration > Catalog > Google Sitemap > Generation Settings**. Enable Generation and set the frequency as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is the appropriate solution for handling multilingual websites, but there is another issue we're facing.
When we created this:

```
Filename   => sitemap-en.xml
Path       => /media/sitemap/
Store View => English
```

The sitemap index generated is correct but the sitemaps within are changing URL to example.com/en/media/sitemap/sitemap-en-1-1.xml which is a 404 and it doesn't exit.

**Note that if we remove the /en/ subdirectory the sitemap opens correctly.**
How to solve this? What are we missing here?
[image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/209473)